# SQL Log entry from bulk insert

Tags: sql, logging, insert, bulk

Huge fan and just signing up as I'm stuck.  I have a set of CSV files that are sent via email and download and saved automatically for nightly reports.  If one of the files are missing then the job fails and I would like to keep the reports from sending and want to base this action on a log.

Below is the beginning of the SP that I created for this.  The imports continue through a couple more files and then write to the main table at the end.  I want to change two things:

1. If the import fails for any file the entire job fails.  I'd like to have the job continue if the file doesn't exist, and,
2. Write the results of each import to a table with a time stamp and a 1 or 0 with the true or false.  Something like: `IF BULK INSERT SUCCESSFUL THEN INSERT INTO TABLE 'TIMEDATESTAMP','COMPANY NUMBER','1' ELSE (do the same except with 0)`

   ```
   USE [Projects]
   GO
   /****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[uspTimeAttendanceImport]    Script Date: 12/26/2013 15:25:43 ******/
   SET ANSI_NULLS ON
   GO
   SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
   GO


   ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[uspTimeAttendanceImport] 

   AS
   begin
   --Create the temp table for staging the data.  Delete if it already exist.
   IF (OBJECT_ID('tempdb..##tblDailyHoursStaging') IS NOT NULL) DROP TABLE ##tblDailyHoursStaging

   create table ##tblDailyHoursStaging
   (
   strWorkDay VARCHAR(50) NULL,
   strEmployeeID VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
   dtmClockDate VARCHAR(14) NOT NULL,
   strCompanyCode VARCHAR(6) NULL,
   strDepartmentCode VARCHAR(6) NULL,
   strEarningCode VARCHAR(8) NULL,
   strEarningType VARCHAR (50) NULL,
   lngAmountEarned VARCHAR (20) NULL,
   lngHoursWorked VARCHAR(10) NULL
   )

   --Insert downloaded time clock data COMPANY 1000
   BULK
   INSERT ##tblDailyHoursStaging
   FROM 'D:\TimeAttendanceData\Flash Report 1000.csv'
   WITH
   (
   FIRSTROW = 2,
   FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',
   ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'
   )
   ```

Comment: TRY/CATCH: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175976.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I would use powershell for this. I assume this is on a Windows platform. By using powershell you only look at the files that exist. You can use transactions within powershell along with a try/catch block. With your proposed solution you will need to alter the procedure if a new csv file is sent.

Comment: Isn't that a little overkill? :)

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I know that this is possible because I have seen SQL SPs at my old company that wrote the results to a log file upon completing a job.  I just need two things: If the CSV doesn't exist then log a 0 and if it does and imports success then log a 1 for the company number.